# Jira subtask disappears from parent story when its status is changed with the drop-down

Tags: jira

The Jira Sprint work view displays stories with all their subtasks in columns corresponding to their status.

You can change a status of a subtask by dragging it from one column to another (for example for Open to Awaiting QA).

If I change the subtask's status not by drag-and-drop but using the drop-down menu of the subtask itself, it completely disappears from the sprint work overview (but it still exists as a subtask of the story).

Is this a bug? I don't understand this behavior and it's causing me to miss subtasks in the overview page.

Comment: I think you mean the GreenHopper work board. Are you using classic GreenHopper or the new rapid board?

Comment: GreenHopper tries to alway display the parent of a subtask even if it is not in the JQL or restriction currently in place. They don't want dangling subtasks in their columns.